# Clear cached options on async select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have an Async react-select (v2) that changes its `loadOptions` based on tabs change. 
The issue is that when switching tabs the select is still showing the results of the previous api call that were cached. The cache needs to be purged every time the tabs change.

```
 <Async
    cacheOptions
    isClearable
    loadOptions={props.loadOptions}
    {...this.selectProps(inputText, props)}
  />
```

I have seen in a few places that the React-Select v2 will include the option to reset the cache for the Async select, but I couldn't find in the documentation an example on how to do it.

Please advise.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/130

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G thanks,this is where I saw written by the owner of react-select, JedWatson that _you can reset the cache in the upcoming v2._

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With an hack, by adding a `key` with some changing prop to the `async` select- I was able to get the results cleared on tab click:

```
 key={this.state.searchBy}
```